# Bootstrap 4 navbar not collapsing on large screen

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement a Navbar using Bootstrap 4. Currently, the Navbar correctly collapses when the viewport is shrunk to mobile size. However, when attempting to toggle menu, nothing happens. The jsFiddle example demonstrates this behavior. I have attached the HTML as well.

Steps I have taken:

- Removing all custom CSS
- Ensuring jQuery link is before Bootstrap JS file
- Script tags in the header and the footer
- Copy and paste exact examples from Bootstrap Docs (and I get the same behavior)
- Ensuring that JS is being used in the Chrome browser
- Validated HTML using WC3 validator
- And of course, read various posts on SO about this issue but none lead to a resolution

jsFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/u7v5jba9/

```html
<title>Site title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i> Brand Name
      </a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
              </button>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link ">Link 1</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link ">Link 2</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link ">Sign In</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link ">Register</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link ">Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse fixed-bottom text-center">
      <h6 class="text-light text-center">Footer</h6>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Check your console: _"Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined"_

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to include Popper as per the [Getting Started Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js).

Use these for your scripts instead.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Updated working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u7v5jba9/1/

**Advice: In future, always open the dev inspector console in your browser to find any error messages.**

Comment: Magic, thanks for the reply.  I was using the dev inspector but didn't see the error message -.-

Comment: Can you please explain why does including those files from CDN is worked instead of including from the project directory?? I've faced the same problem also.

Comment: @FatemaT.Zuhora Including them from the project directory should work fine provided you have the **correct** versions.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong going with me actually, it does not workes when I download and use from my local directory. I did not use any value for `integrity` and `crossorigin`; simply just used `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Answer (score 4):

You can also change the bootstrap reference to the bundled version - bootstrap.**bundle**.min.js - which includes popper.js.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/smoore4/m2dLp71q/

As @Anand Rockzz correctly points out, you still need to add jQuery before this reference.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you miss the order of scripts.
You should always include scripts in this order

1. jquery.js
2. popper.js
3. bootstrap.js

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful ...Since Bootstrap 5 there is a slight change in how collapse works... see code `

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">DATA STRUCTURES &amp; ALGORITHMS JS</button>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample" >
  <form class="form-inline" id="form">
 <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
 <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
</div>
```